# redis-cli command not responding

Tags: redis

I am running a cluster of 6 nodes in my redis cluster. Currently they do not have keys associated with them and 0 slaves have been set up. When I run `redis-cli` my dos prompt just spins.[image: redis cli spinning]

Environment windows server 2012

Redis conf file contents

> port 7000 
>       cluster-enabled yes
>       cluster-config-file nodes.conf
>       cluster-node-timeout 5000
>       appendonly yes
>       loglevel notice
>       logfile "log"

Log File contents

> [3048] 24 Oct 13:21:53.789 * Node configuration loaded, I'm
>   b9000ddb5d4e4d88ee5903e79902c192193dc2ad
>                   *.*
>              *.-`__ ''-._
>
>         _.-`    `.`*.  ''-._           Redis 3.2.100 (00000000/0) 64 bit   .-```` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._
>
>   (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in cluster mode 
>   |`-._`-...-` __...-. ````-.*|'`_.-'|     Port: 7000  |`-.*   `._
>
>   /     _.-'    |     PID: 3048`-._    `-._`-./  _.-'    *.-'
>
>   |`-._`-.*    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
>
>   |`-.*`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io`
>   -.*    `-._`-.**.-'_.-'    *.-'
>
>   |`-._`-.*    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
>
>   |`-.*`-._        _.-'_.-'    |`
>   -.*    `-._`-.**.-'_.-'    _.-'
>         `-._`-.**.-'    _.-'
>
>             `-._        _.-'`
>
>   -.**.-'
>
> [3048] 24 Oct 13:21:53.805 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.100
>   [3048] 24 Oct 13:21:53.805 * The server is now ready to accept
>   connections on port 7000 [2052] 24 Oct 13:24:14.493 * Node
>   configuration loaded, I'm b9000ddb5d4e4d88ee5903e79902c192193dc2ad

***EDIT***

I can still run meetup commands via the terminal. I know the IP is invalid, I changed it on purpose.

redis-cli -c -h 300.300.62.3 -p 7000 cluster meet 10.144.62.3 7001

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use redis-cli in interactive mode you need to do one of two things:

1. Install the redis node with the default settings: IP 127.0.0.1 and port 6379. Then when you use `redis-cli` it will autoconnect to the default settings.
2. If like me you had to change the IP and the port you then cannot use the default settings. You will need to call the cli like this `redis-cli -h 10.0.0.1 -p 7000`, changing 10.0.0.1 to be the correct IP.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and `redis-cli` didn't work. you can solved it just by run **cmd** as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

To install redis-cli on windows -

download redis from the below link
**https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases/tag/win-3.0.504**

- **Redis-x64-3.0.504.zip** and extract it
  now execute - cp redis-cli.exe /usr/bin/

After that add the environment variable -
open environment variables open PATH -> NEW ->PASTE THE PATH WHERE YOU HAVE DOWNLOADED THE **Redis-x64-3.0.504**
In my case the path is  E:\redisfolder\Redis-x64-3.0.504

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows 11**

After [installation](https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases/tag/v5.0.14.1), Must add/validate the **PATH** *>* `C:\Program Files\Redis` added into your environment variables.

Test > Close the Terminal & Reopen.

```
PS C:\Users\sannjayy> redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> ping
PONG
127.0.0.1:6379>
```